# Google Drive File Stream syncing forever

Tags: google-apps

Google Drive Files Stream is stuck syncing since installation. I tried waiting a few days, I tried a clean install, nothing seems to work. It's especially annoying since the Activity Monitor on my mac lists the Google Drive's process as using 90% of the CPU.
I'm on OSx Catalina 10.15.1 - mbp 15" 2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling spotlight for the newly created Google Drive Volume. It worked for me. Go to Preferences -> Spotlight and then to the Privacy tab. Add the Google Drive volume to the ignored volumes.

The problem is that the spotlight indexing process tries to access all the files in the cloud.

Any process that visits all files inside a drive might trigger this situation, e.g. an antivirus or similar stuff.

Hope this helps.